Why is a bigger camera sensor better at low light than a smaller one?
People say a bigger camera sensor is better for light performance as the photo sensors are bigger and hence let in more light. But couldn't you just let the same light in and focus it down onto the smaller size of a smaller image sensor?

if you were to ask this on photography.SE, you might get a different set of insights.  Just be sure you read the rules on crossposting (stack exchange doesn;t like naive crossposting).  I think this might be an interesting different set of resuts

actually, this question exists on photography.se.  interestingly there is a wide array of answers.

Too tired to research and reference a proper answer right now, but you're on the right track. The area of the entrance pupil (the size of the lens, the amount of light you gather) is in some ways more important than the sensor size. But there are legit physics and manufacturing reasons why it's easier to put a big lens in front of a big sensor than to put a big lens in front of a small sensor, if you care about image quality!

Think of light as rain falling on your sensor. A bright light is a downpour. A dim light is a sprinkle. You want to know how much rain fell on a patch of ground.
You can set up a funnel and a test tube. All the rain that falls on the funnel collects in the test tube. If it is drizzling out, you don't get enough collected rain to work with. So you get a bigger funnel to collect more rain. All the rain goes into the same test tube. But now you have enough water to work with.

This is really an engineering issue, not a physics one.
The problem is this:
If you need a bigger lens to gather in all that light, it is, by necessity, going to make a bigger camera.  As the lens is larger, the camera housing is larger and you may as well use a bigger sensor anyway.
Using a larger sensor (or more precisely, larger individual pixels) has additional benefits.  Typically the larger sensor will be able not only to gather more light, but the relative level of noise in a big sensor compared to a small one is lower.  This is the Signal To Noise Ratio.  This allows the sensor to capture lower levels of light more accurately (less noisily).  You can trade off this capability to increase the dynamic range (the number of levels of light) you can accurately capture.  This is very useful.
There's another issue : out of focus detail.  It is very useful, in isolating subjects from the background, to be able to control the level of blur that you get.  This is done by a combination of focal length choice (which does relate to sensor size as well) and aperture.  Larger sensors allow more blur.  This is a curse and a blessing, but in practical terms they can resolve detail (where it's needed) better.
So this choice of sensor size has other side effects.
